# What is the alternative instead of using gets(c) and gets(s) in this code?

Tags: c, scanf, gets

EDIT:

Question:

Write a program to find the number of times that a given word (i.e. a short string) occurs in a
sentence (i.e. a long string!). Read data from standard input. The first line is a single word, which
is followed by general text on the second line.

Sample Input:

```
the
the cat sat on the mat
```

Sample Output:

```
2
```

I tried using scanf before but it fails to read the entire sentence and just checks the first word and returns 1 as the answer instead of 2

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
char s[200000], c[20], v = ' ';
int i = 0, j, f, n = 0;
gets(c);
gets(s);

while (i < strlen(s))
{
    j = 0;
    f = 0;
    while (j < strlen(c))
    {
        if (s[i++] != c[j++])
        {
            f = 1;
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ((f == 0) && (i == strlen(s) || s[i] == ' ') && (v == ' '))
    {
        n++;
        v = s[i++];
    }
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you provide the definition of the problem too, instead of making us reverse engineer it?

Comment: Please note that you execute `strlen()` in every iteration of your loops, yet they remain constant. You are wasting cycles.

Comment: By the way, please read the information on how to write a good question. I'm not saying it's very bad, but not exactly what this website is supposed to facilitate.

Comment: @szpanczyk Added the exact question.@Paul Ogilvie Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: Sorry.Didn't think it through

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Comment: The idea is that instead of:
 - asking for general help in your particular problem
 - you should ask for particular help in a general problem 
:)

Comment: Ok.What is the alternative to using gets in this particular problem?

Comment: Can't you even click the link that You've been provided? :/

Comment: I saw that link.I tried using fgets and gets_s,they are giving errors?Is there any quick-fix to this?

Comment: @A.Vik: What errors are you getting with `fgets`?  Also, realize you don't have to read the entire second line into memory all at once to do this - in fact, that's making your life harder at the moment.

Comment: Too few arguments...

Comment: @A.Vik: Did you check the man page for `fgets` (or at least google for it)?  It does take more arguments than `gets` (and has different behavior where newlines are concerned).

Comment: I think that the problem of counting the occurrences of a _word_ in a sentence is only a particular case of the more general problem of counting the occurrences of a _substring_ in a string. I mean, given the word "the" and the sentence "the pen is there", what is your expected output, 1 or 2?

Comment: 1 should be the answer in that case

Comment: John Bode yes,I am right now trying to correct the code....

Comment: "I tried using scanf before but it fails to read the entire sentence" -->  lacks specificity.  There are countless ways to use `scanf()`, some will work for you here, others will not.  As this post lacks the `scanf()` code, the post is unclear as to what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution ([answer](http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-occurence-particular-word-string/)) of the program you are trying to implement. This also provide the correct method of getting a string.

Hope this help in either ways!

Comment: Link only answers are not a good idea, expecially when that page cannot be reached...

Answer (score 0):

> What is the alternative instead of using gets(c) and gets(s) in this code?

Instead of `char c[20]; gets(c);`, use the following

```
// Read a line of text
char c[20+1];  // 1 more for the \n
if (fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin) == NULL) {
  // Handle EOF or input error in some fashion
  puts("Unexpected EOF or input error");
  return 1;
}
```

Lop off the `'\n'` [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359)

```
// lop off a potential trailing '\n'.
c[strcspn(c, "\n")] = '\0';
```

The rest of code may still have other issues.